# Laravel: route [/login] not defined

Tags: laravel, routes

But it's

> | GET|HEAD | login | login | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,GlobalRequest,guest  |

It seems to happens when the session expires, but I don't get why.
if I refresh the page problem goes away.
I think the problem is with the auth middleware.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try 'php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Will try thanks, it's a kinda random issue tho, I won't be able the check if that fixed it or not.

Comment: Sure, let us know

Comment: because there is no route named `/login` ... sounds like you are passing a path to a route helper instead of the route name

Comment: As @lagbox says, the key bit of data you haven't shown us is how did you get to see this error?  Or, in standard SO form, show us your code.

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I'm afraid issue persists. 
Don'tPanic it happens anywhere with code that works usually fine.
I'll edit the OP with some laravel's debugging screens.

Comment: `it happens anywhere` - as with most bugs, we need to see **the code** that throws this error. Somewhere you are trying to reference a route *named* `/login`, but you (unsurprisingly) have no such route.  If it has a name, it almost certainly would not include `/`. You are mixing up route *names* with route *URIs*.  Also, [why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

Would seem like you have `/login` instead of `login` in your code where a route name is required instead of a path. Check any middleware you have assigned to the routes that are throwing this error, such as the `auth` middleware.

Also would be helpful to know what version of Laravel you are using.

Comment: Ahh, that's supposed to be the route name right? That's not my code, it's Laravel core. BTW, I'm using v7.0.5

Comment: It's weird, I'm checking file's changes history and it totally differs from the version I have. I don't really get it.
 https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php